# elasticsearch-DSL lib set default value for Text field on saving Document

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

how do we check if a Field object from elasticsearch-DSL lib (e.g. Text, Integer, Keyword) contains no value, say None or empty string? On such case, I need to set the field in Document object with some sort of default but dynamic value, before saving the Document into ES. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is to override `save()` method and do it there, you can see an example of it here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/examples/parent_child.py#L84-L85

Comment: Since the field is initialised with Field object, I expected "if my_field is None:" will evaluate to False. Surprisingly, I just tested it out and the evaluation turns True instead. Since code in the link hints me that my understanding was incorrect, I think it's fair to mark this as answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible with current implementation. Details are available [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17659). However, if you are using elasticsearch rest client, you can add logic to generate some random String/Number before saving.